# how does for loop evaluates in c

Tags: c

I am trying to learn c programming and I came across this problem which I dont seem to understand. Here is the syntax
double x;

```
  int flag = 0;
  for(x = 0; x <= 2.0; x+=0.1) {
      printf("%f\n",x);
      printf("%d\n", x==0.300000);
      if(x==0.3) {
         printf("yes\n");
         flag = 1;
      }
  }
  if(flag == 0) {
      printf("no\n");
  }
```

how come the output is no. I though when the loop reaches 0.3, the flag would be set to one and yes would be printed. How come that is not the case?

Comment: Please don't include line numbers in code snippets - it means people can't paste it into an editor and compile/run it.

Comment: 1/10 is periodic in binary (just like 1/3 is periodic in decimal), so it can't be stored accurately as a floating pointing point number.